# How spl_autoload_register works?

Tags: php, function, spl

Today I met with the spl_autoload_register. Well, Its functionality and flexibility are really great.

However, I just wonder how this SPL function works. Lets say I have a file that is named as Animal.php. On the another hand, I have another file that Index.php includes the code in the below.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   require_once($class.'.php');
});

$animal = new Animal;
$animal->speak();
```

This SPL function understand that I create an object from Animal class and calls the Animal.php file which it should be called.

What happens the behind the scenes of this function? I mean how does it resolves that I need Animal.php file? I don't assign any value to $class variable or pass anything to anonymous function. But somehow, it understands what i need.

What is explanation of this?

Comment: It doesn't resolve that you need Animal.php file, it only knows that you want to construct a class whose name is Animal, and this class isn't defined in the current context, so "Animal" will be passed to the callback function.

Comment: @shingo Well, actually this doesn't reply my question. Okay, the function doesn't resolve file but still it passes the "Animal" to callback function. But how? It's clearly passing it via $class parameter in callback function. My question is, how it automatically detects and passes "Animal" to the callback function? As I said, I just wonder behind the scene.

Comment: I think I have explained. In another words, when the runtime executes "new Animal", it knows 1) you want to construct an object, 2) the type name is "Animal". So it tries to search the class "Animal" definition in its context, when it fails, it will pass this name to the registered callback.

Comment: Yeah that is how algorithm supposed to be. I was just wondering the source code of this function. I mean i want to see how php handles it. It would be great to seeing the algorithm of this function in the code. For now, I found this.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/php_spl.c

I think, this is what I looking for. However, I'm still open the suggestions or comments.

Thank you for reply!